# Diagnosing a blank screen at drive decryption - garuda linux

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, luks

I have a dual boot setup of windows and garuda Linux which have been working fine (efi). I've been working mainly in garuda and haven't done a reboot for a while.

My system drive is luks encrypted and after the grub boot screen I am given a prompt to enter my password to decrypt the system drive.

The graphical prompt to enter my password appears as usual. Along with some text telling me I can hit escape to see the terminal. So usually I can blindly enter the password or hit escape key to see a text prompt for the password and the response to the password entry. (Usually good for finding issues)

For some reason now upon hitting any key. Either to enter password or escape key I get a black screen. Entering the password does nothing and there is nothing I can do or see. The machine is however responsive to ctrl+alt+delete. Upon hitting that I see the login graphic prompt briefly appear before reboot (so it seems to still be there).

My grub seems fine and I have tried a reconfig from a grub boot disk. The windows install is fine and I can boot to it. From grub live environment I can unlock the drive via cli and chroot into the machine.

Any advice to diagnose what is happening would be appreciated.